# Desplegar texto con JavaScript y CSS

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quiero lograr una simple función donde un enlace despliegue un texto, con javascript, pero que a su vez tenga una animación tipo transition:duration, pero no consigo hacerlo, la animación no funciona.

- Intenté solamente con CSS pero tengo una WebView y al desplegar se cierra la app, y quiero una alternativa para saber si funciona.

CSS:

```
input[id^="spoiler"] + label{cursor:pointer}input[id^="spoiler"] ~ .spoiler{height:0;overflow:hidden;opacity:0}input[id^="spoiler"]:checked + label + .spoiler{height:auto;opacity:1;transition-duration:1s}
```

¿Algún código que lo haga? Quiero que sea con javascript y CSS, en lo posible, dejando de lado el anterior código.

Comment: Hola, agrega el código que tienes hasta el momento para que podamos ayudarte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero te pueda ayudar:

```
<p><a href="javascript:mostrar();">Mostrar</a></p>
<div id="flotante" style="display:none;">
     <div id="close"><a href="javascript:cerrar();">cerrar</a></div>
     Este es un div ocultar
</div>


<script languague="javascript">
        function mostrar() {
            div = document.getElementById('flotante');
            div.style.display = '';
        }

        function cerrar() {
            div = document.getElementById('flotante');
            div.style.display = 'none';
        }
</script>
```

Comment: Rolando, me serviría pero le falta la animación.